# Plotting data with only month and day

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, matplotlib

I have a dataframe that looks like:

```
         Date   Data_Value
19      2005-01-01  156
79      2005-01-02  139
99      2005-01-03  133
29356   2007-01-04  106
29388   2007-01-05  128
```

I want to plot it as just the month and day, ignoring the year, however when I do the following:

```
data['Date']=pd.to_datetime(data['Date'])
data['Date']=data['Date'].dt.strftime('%m-%d')
plt.figure()
plt.plot(data['Date'],data['Data_Value'],'-o')
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '12-31'
```

How can I bypass this?

Comment: Are you using an older version of matplotlib?

Comment: When you use `strftime` you automatically convert your Datetime to a string. Since you have multiple years in your data do you all want multiple lines for each year?

Comment: I don't want the graph to be dependent on the year. This is weather data, so I'm trying to find the max throughout a few years on the specific day. I only want the data to be tied to the month-day.

Answer (score -1):

Here is my solution. It works for me.

Changing years in `data['Date']` column to **2000** (or others).

```
data['Date_2'] = data['Date'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(year = 2000))
```

Then plot it as just the month and day.

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
ax = data.plot(x = 'Date_2', y = 'Data_Value')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%m-%d'))
```